Snapping support for moving polygons in OpenLayers
OpenLayers has an example on how to implement snapping support for points on a map. Though I'm investigating whether snapping is also supported for moving and snapping polygons as a whole, instead of moving and snapping single points.
Though I have not found any documentation or example illustrating this.
Looking in the API docs of OpenLayers, I see that Snap extends from PointerEvent, and I assume that the snapping behaviour only supports snapping at the position of the mouse pointer, which is not what I need.
Am I missing something? Or am I correct that snapping polygons as a whole currently is not supported in OpenLayers?

Use the Translate interaction as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html to move the polygons
const translate = new Translate({
  source: vector.getSource(),
});

const snap = new Snap({
  source: vector.getSource(),
});

const map = new Map({
  interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([translate, snap]),
  layers: [vector],
  ...

To snap one edge to another you need to drag the translated polygon by its edge.  To avoid the Translate interaction dragging the interior of a polygon you could style fill and stroke separately and use a layer filter.
Example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.2.4/ol.css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.2.4/dist/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/data/vector/us-states.json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'black',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
});

const vectorFill = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vector.getSource(),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'red',
    }),
  }),
})

const translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  source: vector.getSource(),
  layers: [vector],
});

const snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
  source: vector.getSource(),
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults.defaults().extend([translate, snap]),
  layers: [vectorFill, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-100, 38.5]),
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>




thanks for your reply Mike, I chcecked the Translate interaction and it demos moving of polygons, but not snapping of them right? I was explicitly looking for snapping as well.

You will need to add a Snap interaction after adding the Translate interaction.  I have added an example to the answer.

this indeed does the trick, thanks Mike!
